# Telethon: check if client instance is logged in

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I am trying to log the user into the account using the telegram bot API, and I can't find a way to check if the client instance has access to an account...

this is my instance:

```py
client = TelegramClient(client_name, API_ID, API_HASH)
```

by using `client.start()` it detects if the user is logged in or not, so i must have access to that too...

Comment: Without more details I can't give you a great answer. I personally would dive into the [source code](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/master/telethon/client/auth.py) if the behavior has not been documented. Otherwise, you may consider consider opening an issue on GitHub to ask for help from the maintainers. It looks like they are fairly active on the issue board and I imagine would be happy to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`get_me()`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.users.UserMethods.get_me): it will return the current logged in user or `None` if there isn't one.

```
client = TelegramClient(client_name, API_ID, API_HASH)
if (await client.get_me()):
    # client has an user logged in
else:
    # client hasn't an user logged in
```

Also, if you take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/master/telethon/client/auth.py#L142), you'll see that `start()` is doing the same.

Comment: Honorable mention to [`client.is_user_authorized`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.users.UserMethods.is_user_authorized) which makes more semantic sense.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer may fail if you don't connect the client instance anywhere else. Make sure to connect before attempting to perform requests:

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient

async def main():
    client = TelegramClient(session_name, api_id, api_hash)

    await client.connect()
    if await client.is_user_authorized():
        ... # no need to login
    else:
        ... # client would need to login
```

Do not use `async with` or `client.start()` if your goal is checking whether the session is logged-in. In Telethon v1, these will perform the interactive login flow and prompt for phone, code and password as needed.

If you want to handle that manually or in another manner, use `client.send_code_request` and `client.sign_in` yourself.