# How To Check If Telethon Session Is Valid

Tags: telethon

I am using StringSessions and many times session string does not work because it was revoked.I have made a gui for login but due the revocation of session, telethon asks for new login and the  login procedure appears in cmd.
Is there a way which can tell me whether the session string is valid or a method which  connects using sessions and returns error instead of asking for login details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Telethon: check if client instance is logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64756983/telethon-check-if-client-instance-is-logged-in)

Answer (score 0):

```
client = TelegramClient(StringSession("string_session"), api_id=API_ID, api_hash=API_HASH)

await client.connect()
print(await client.is_user_authorized()) #returns true if the user is authorized
```